# Try to create cluster PostgreSQL Debian

Tags: postgresql, debian

I try to create a cluster with log in folder using PostgreSQL on Debian 8

First I create **db** folder, and mark postgres as owner.

Then I create **logs** folder, and and **logs/log** file.

Try to create cluster:

```
$: pg_createcluster -d usr/db/db -l usr/db/db/log --start 9.5 db

Creating new cluster 9.5/db ...
  config /etc/postgresql/9.5/db
  data   /usr/db/db
  locale C.UTF-8
  socket /var/run/postgresql
  port   5434
Warning: systemd does not know about the new cluster yet. Operations like "service postgresql start" will not handle it. To fix, run:
  sudo systemctl daemon-reload
Warning: the cluster will not be running as a systemd service. Consider using systemctl:
  sudo systemctl start postgresql@9.5-db
```

Run:

```
$: sudo service postgresql start
$: sudo systemctl daemon-reload
$: sudo systemctl start postgresql@9.5-db
Job for postgresql@9.5-db.service failed. See 'systemctl status postgresql@9.5-db.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
$: journalctl -xn
    Sep 30 12:20:21 artem-debian sudo[30438]: root : TTY=pts/3 ; PWD=/usr/db ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/systemctl start p
Sep 30 12:20:21 artem-debian sudo[30438]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by artem(uid=0)
Sep 30 12:20:22 artem-debian postgresql@9.5-db[30441]: Cluster is already running.
Sep 30 12:20:22 artem-debian systemd[1]: postgresql@9.5-db.service: control process exited, code=exited status=2
Sep 30 12:20:22 artem-debian systemd[1]: Failed to start PostgreSQL Cluster 9.5-db.
-- Subject: Unit postgresql@9.5-db.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit postgresql@9.5-db.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Sep 30 12:20:22 artem-debian systemd[1]: Unit postgresql@9.5-db.service entered failed state.
Sep 30 12:20:22 artem-debian sudo[30438]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root

$: pg_lsclusters

9.5 db 5434 down   postgres /usr/db/db         /usr/db/db/log

$: service postgresql status
● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Fri 2016-09-30 13:59:41 EEST; 12min ago
  Process: 31652 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 31652 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   CGroup: /system.slice/postgresql.service

$: sudo pg_ctlcluster 9.5 db start
Redirecting start request to systemctl
Job for postgresql@9.5-db.service failed. See 'systemctl status postgresql@9.5-db.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.


$: systemctl status postgresql@9.5-db.service
● postgresql@9.5-db.service - PostgreSQL Cluster 9.5-db
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql@.service; disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2016-09-30 14:17:07 EEST; 2s ago
  Process: 32536 ExecStart=postgresql@%i --skip-systemctl-redirect %i start (code=exited, status=2)

Sep 30 14:17:07 artem-debian postgresql@9.5-db[32536]: Cluster ...
Sep 30 14:17:07 artem-debian systemd[1]: postgresql@9.5-db.ser...2
Sep 30 14:17:07 artem-debian systemd[1]: Failed to start PostgreSQL Cluster ....
Sep 30 14:17:07 artem-debian systemd[1]: Unit postgresql@9.5-finstatement.co....
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

Comment: Check this (not sure if it's relevant): https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/87hb5xwg94.fsf%40comcast.net